# Prevent Kafka Streams Consumer from writing offsets / wait for one stream to consume all records before starting the second stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

this is a 2in1 question regarding streams.

Im working on a service which consists of two streams. One (the first) should consume an entire topic, receiving key/value pairs and storing their information in a local HashMap

As soon as this stream has no lag anymore, the second stream starts and consumes another topic. From the consumed data and one of its attributes, it is decided based on the HashMap entries whether a record is dropped or further processed.
Therefore the first stream needs to reach the end of its topic before the second stream starts.
I would like to keep the service stateless and thus not save the data in a state store. This creates two problems:

1. A normal Kafka consumer can be configured  to prevent it from writing its offsets and thus consume the topic over and over each time it is restartet.

```yaml
enable.auto.commit = false
auto.offset.reset = earliest
```

With streams however this does not seam to work. My temporary solution is to generate an ApplicationID with a random part in order to ignore previously written offsets.
This generates a new consumer-group for each instance, resulting in many groups on the broker.

-> Is there a way to configure a streaming client to NOT write offsets?

2. In order for the second stream to wait until the first topic is consumed i tried different implementations. My last approach looks as follows:

```java
      try {
        firstStreams.start();
        // Waiting for consumer to start...
        while (computeLag(firstStreams.metrics().entrySet()) < 1) {
          sleep(100);
        }
        // Waiting for Lag to reach 0
        while (computeLag(firstStreams.metrics().entrySet()) > 1) {
          sleep(100);
        }

        secondStream.start();
        shutdownLatch.await();
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }
  
   private static double computeLag(Set<? extends Map.Entry<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics) {
    return metrics.stream()
        .filter(entries -> entries.getKey().name().equals("records-lag"))
        .map(entry -> entry.getValue().metricValue().toString())
        .map(Double::parseDouble)
        .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
        .sum();
  }
```

The consumer metric will return 0.0 as long as the consumer is not running. After a successful start it returns the lag over all partitions.

This version works but it seems wrong and complicated.

-> is there a proper way to wait for a stream to reach "the end"?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 0):

> configure a streaming client to NOT write offsets?

With Kafka Streams, not that I know of. At least, not with stateful processing

> is there a proper way to wait for a stream to reach "the end"?

There is not. What you've done seems okay, but I don't think it scales beyond one partition / instance (your lag metric would be computed for all instances, not only the current one, meanwhile your Hashmap would only have data from partitions assigned to the current instance).

---

> receiving key/value pairs and storing their information in a local HashMap

This isn't really an acceptable use case for Kafka Steams. You should use a KTable and Interactive Queries for lookups, or joins to do filtering of other Streams

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer for your input and bein clear on the stream vs table topic.

My Idea was to not use a state store but as I read your lines I'm starting to doubt that idea.

If I'd implement a globalKTable and save its content in a state store:
- the second stream would not need to wait (given the store is loaded back into the globalKTable before the stream starts)
- and also the consumer feeding the KTable could work with its normal application id since offsets would not be problematic.

I'll rewrite the code to check this out.

Comment: I'd suggest separately deploying the "second app". You should be able to remotely monitor the lag of the first app by exporting JMX metrics, or using tools like Burrow. Then block that stream startup until you reach low lag